# React: text in state rendered as it is

Tags: reactjs

I have a react code and I want to render state as `{this.state.text}`. It is rendered, but not as expected. Here's the state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: "<i>Hello, this is Introduction</i>"};
}
```

This is rendered as:

```
<i>Hello, this is Introduction</i>
```

Is there a way to render it as

*Hello, this is Introduction*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of many ways to do it is to put text in state like this:

```
this.state = {text: "Hello, this is Introduction"};
```

and render the state's text using italic tag.like this

```
<i>{this.state.text}</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
<i dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.text}} />
```

But it's safer to use:

```
<i>{this.state.text}</i>
```